# Enterprise Validation check login true or false and retrieve user information?

Tags: html, web-application-security

I am building an web app that is going to run on an intranet. I would like to query the client's system to determine if they are logged in with their Enterprise credentials. Also, if possible read the credential to find the name of the user. I am not sure where to start with this and any resources or tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

I have previously done something similar with excel dashboards, where I have used the user information to display names on splashscreens, but no idea how to implement that with a web app.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd start here: https://jwt.io/ (look at the example)

Comment: Thank you! @root